# Capture string from API Result in Python

Tags: python, string

I am using python for an API. Based on the API Call I get the below result.
I need to capture the progressId - `"ES_0oEfQzNILXaBNuS"` into a string and reuse it in the next API Call.

How do i capture this as a string in Python ?

```
print(response.text)
{"result":{"progressId":"ES_0oEfQzNILXaBNuS","percentComplete":0.0,"status":"inProgress"},"meta":{"requestId":"4ad2749a-7029-4d16-a691-f605bb5fb6f9","httpStatus":"200 - OK"}}
```

Comment: use response.json instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:
`response.json().get('result').get('progressId')`

Comment: `response.json` --> `response.json()`